# Equivalent to nearest in Dart, specifically DartPolymer?

Tags: dart, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I am trying to figure out a way to carry out something similar to jquery's nearest function.  Ex:

```
$("a.test").nearest(".group-parent");
```

but in dart.

I was looking through the HtmlElement class to see if there was a way i could do as above but have not found anything really which would walk up the tree until it found the selector (or null, etc).

Is there something in place that can already be leveraged to do such a thing?

I was thinking to just create a function which will loop through the parents until parents = null (or whatever returns for the document).

```
HtmlElement findNearestClass(HtmlElement node, String classString){
  if (node == null) return null;
  if (node.classes.contains(classString)) return node;
  return findNearestClass(node.parent, classString);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `.closest()`?

Comment: This might do what you want https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_utils/blob/master/lib/browser/html.dart#L49

Comment: @jinglesthula thanks for that.  I mixed up i think.  Closest is what i wanted, yeah.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think that is what i would want.  Maybe ill implement some of code in our application. :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  I noticed the Element class within Dart:html, has a closest(selector) function and was looking through that.  I noticed that it also is the parent class for HtmlElement, so i was thinking that concept of closest might be just as good as yours?  I didnt see any documentation for it to describe it other than its signature really:  `Element closest(String selector);`

Comment: Didn't know that. Sure if it does what yiu want

Comment: Im not sure myself.  I have to look into it more... but if you put an answer down referencing the Element class and your codebase, im sure it is answer worthy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with Gunter, We determined the following:

When you are creating a component with Dart, you will extend `PolymerElement` which based on the `HtmlElement` it seems.  `HtmlElement` has a parent `Element`.

I was looking as such, and noticed in the `Element` class, there is actually a *closest* function which has the following signature

```
Element closest(String selectors);
```

which seems to resolve what I want, and can use References to HtmlElements or PolymerElmeent to do similar.

A common scenario which might be useful for your component might be something like:

```
(MouseEvent mouse){
  HtmlElement target = mouse.target;
  HtmlElement closestFoo = target.closest(".foo");
}
```

As an alternative, Gunter did link this, which has a closest implementation you could leverage.  https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_utils/blob/master/lib/browser/html.dart#L49